# When a rotation has period.

Tags: geometry, transformation, isometry

A period of a transformation $f$ in this context is the least natural number $n$ such that $f^{n}=id$, when it exists.

My book says this claim, which I  couldn't prove: A rotation have a period if and only if the measure of its rotation angle is a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem

Comment: Can you at least prove that if the angle is a rational multiple of $\pi$, then it has a period?

Comment: I tried: If the angle is $\frac{n \pi}{m}$, then composing the rotation $m$ times I would get angle $n \pi$, which is congruent to $0$ or $\pi$. In the first case it's done, in the second case I can compose again $m$ times and it'll be congruent to $0$, by simmetry of circle. Is it correct?

Comment: (And then I'll have a nonempty set of naturals, which by Well-Ordering Principle will have least element)

Comment: Yes, good! Now, suppose you have some angle $\theta$, and you rotate $m$ times, and you get something congruent to zero, modulo $2\pi$. What does that tell you about $\theta$?

Comment: Then I'll have $m . \theta = 2 . \pi . k $, then $ \theta = \frac{2 . \pi . k}{m}$. since $2.k$ is an integer, then $\theta$ is rational with $\pi$.

Comment: Good! So, can you write up and post an answer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gerry Myerson I was able to find the answer.

$(\Rightarrow)$

Suppose $\theta = \frac{n . \pi}{m}$. Then composing the rotation $m$ times will get to the angle $n . \pi$, which is either congruent to $0 \mod 2\pi$ or congruent to $\pi \mod 2\pi$. Suppose it is congruent to $\pi \mod 2\pi$. Then, by the symmetry of the circle, composing the rotation $m$ times again will get to an angle congruent to $0 \mod 2\pi$. Then we have a non-empty list of natural numbers, which by the Well-Ordering Principle will have least element, then the rotation has a period.

$(\Leftarrow)$
Suppose a rotation has period. Then rotating $m$ times will get to an angle congruent to $0 \mod 2\pi$, which means $m.\theta = 2 . \pi . k$, for some integer $k$, then $\theta = \frac{2. \pi . k}{m}$. Since $2 . k$ is an integer, $\theta$ is rational with $\pi$.

$\square$